# JupyterHub populate user home with notebooks (and data)

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I have a `JupyterHub` server hosted on an Ubuntu machine.

(Mainly) since I want to avoid adding hundreds of potential users to the machine I opted to use `c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'jupyterhub.auth.DummyAuthenticator'` (with a password)

The Spawner I use is
`c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'jupyterhub.spawner.SimpleLocalProcessSpawner'` although I also tried `'jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner'`.

I want users to have **some pre-populated notebooks** once they log in.

I first tried https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/content/share-data.html putting the data in `/etc/skel` put it wasn't copied.

Then, according to various docs I could set `c.Spawner.pre_spawn_hook = populate_user_home` (tried also `c.SimpleLocalProcessSpawner.pre_spawn_hook = populate_user_home`) and have that method copy the files I want over to the user's home.

The method I have looks something like:

```
def populate_user_home(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name
    # DummyAuthenticator creates users in /tmp
    volume_path = os.path.join('/tmp', username)
    if not os.path.exists(volume_path):
        os.mkdir(volume_path, 0o777)
        copyDirectory(<path_to_tutorials>, os.path.join(volume_path, 'tutorials'))
```

Problem is that this method **is never called!**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there another (simpler?) way to populate the home of new users?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not `pre_spawn_hook`, but several other small issues.

1. Calling `print` in the hook's code doesn't reach the log. Method was called.
2. Apparently `SimpleLocalProcessSpawner` creates the user folder before calling the hook, so copy was never called
3. the `os.mkdir` actually causes `copytree` to fail because dest folder exists